# Can Pytest only instantiates one class object to test all its methods?

Tags: python, pytest

I think this should be a very common scenario, for example, if you have a class and a few methods for it. If you want to write unittest for them, like test_method_1, test_method_2, ... test_method_n, I do not want to instantiate the class object for each of these test functions, it could be redundant or inefficient. However, I read the doc for Pytest, it looks to me for example by using fixture decoration, although it appears to write class instantiation only once, actually this instantiation would be called every time when it passes to a new test function. Is there a way not to do this but instead I just create the class object only once, and all tests are done within this object ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixtures can have different scopes, or, in other words, be called once for every function that uses it, or once for every test module that uses it, or once for every test session that uses it. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session

This sample script will fail if you use the default scope (function) and pass if you use another scope.

```
import pytest

SCOPE="function"
#SCOPE="session"

class Shared(object):

    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_id = Shared.counter
        Shared.counter += 1


@pytest.fixture(scope=SCOPE)
def shared_instance():
    instance = Shared()

    yield instance


def test_one(shared_instance):
    assert shared_instance.instance_id == 0
def test_two(shared_instance):
    assert shared_instance.instance_id == 0
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I am trying to find. thank you!

Comment: @Tian I am glad it helped. Can you mark the answer as accepted, please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers